# Почему в Go принято возвращать указатель на структуру?

Tags: golang

Немного посматриваю на го, но не понимаю, почему в го принято возвращать именно указатель на структуру, а не саму структуру, например.

```
type service struct { 
    name string
    someService *anotherService 
}

func newService(name string) *service {
    return &service{
       name: name, 
       someService: newSomeService(),
    }
}
```

При чем независимо от размера структуры, всегда возвращают указатель, это же дороже, здесь будет, как минимум, две аллокации

Comment: Вернуть/передать структуру тоже самое, что сделать ее копию (так же как в с/с++)

Comment: Это не дороже, это быстрее.

Comment: @zed вот пример бенчмарков https://medium.com/eureka-engineering/understanding-allocations-in-go-stack-heap-memory-9a2631b5035d

Comment: Бенчмарк лишь сравнивает скорость хипа и стека, но тут и без него очевидно, что стек быстрее. Он для того и придуман. Но после того, как структура создана, её обычно нужно передавать из функций туда-сюда. И вот тут и получается выигрыш - гораздо быстрее положить на стек указатель (8 байт), чем всю структуру целиком.

Comment: указатели вполне нормальное дело даже для ассемблера, в машинных коммандах в которые все языки так или иначе преобразуются много комманд которые работают именно с указателями, вот и судите дороже это или нет.